# Is there any free tool available to check app's compatibility devices?

Tags: android, testing, app-store

I need a free tool that could help me review a list of compatible devices for my  app.

Comment: You must know the Android versions supported by your app, so a device is compatible if it has the minimum version supported or newer. Also when uploading the app to google play it shows a list of compatible and incompatible devices.

Comment: As a tester, can i find any emulators or tools online to check an app compatibility on multiple android devices (without owing those devices)?